# How to bring feature branch in sync with develop branch?

Tags: git, github, merge

Master is the main branch.

Develop branch is created from master branch.

Feature 1 branch is created from develop branch.

Scenario 1: In an ideal scenario I will make changes to Feature 1 branch code, add, commit and push changes to server. Then raise a pull request to merge feature 1 branch with develop branch.

Q1) At this point (pull request) do I have an option to do merge vs rebase on the server? Or is it always merge?

Q2) Assuming I had multiple commits on feature 1 branch, after the pull request is completed, do all the commits from feature 1 branch get stored in history of develop branch? or only a single merge commit will be stored?

Scenario 2: While I am working on feature 1 branch, another developer has made changes to develop branch on the server.

Q3) Now how can I get my Feature 1 branch in sync with latest code from develop branch?

Is the solution to do a code pull from server develop branch into local devlop branch. And then merge/rebase the local develop branch onto the local feature 1 branch and then push the feature 1 branch to the server, followed by pull request to merge this code with develop branch?

Comment: Q1) before push better to rebase against *develop* and then merge on the server side your PR. Q2) Entire history. Merge commit may be present (forced) or not. Q3) Same answer as Q1. P.S. No need to have a special branch locally (default configuration when clone without any special options), it will be in index and it's enough to use it as a base.

Comment: Is my suggested solution incorrect?

Comment: In this scheme I didn't get what happenes to master on the server. Nevertheless, it seems master it's not relevant now. So, just do always feature -> develop (rebase) and develop -> feature (merge). In this scenario we consider your develop branch published and all developers may work with it by above scheme with minimum conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers are as follow

#### Scenario 1:

Q1 Answer: It is always merged.

Q2 Answer: Multiple commits from feature branch and final merged commit in develop branch will be stored.

#### Scenario 2:

Q3 Answer: Yes your process is correct.